# Mysql character set decoding from utf8_unicode_ci to shift jis

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, character-encoding, mysql-error-1064

i have tried many approach to convert `utf8_unicode_ci` value in `MySQL` column from `utf8_unicode_ci` to `shift_jis` but it not getting fixed.

The original column value was in `shift_jis` and it got convert when new hosting used. now the value seems garbage but it is showing good at website front-end.

The table column value are:  `ƒEƒCƒ“ƒhEƒŠƒ“ƒO`
[table column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsiQF.png) and the `character set` are [character set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok4De.png).

i have tried  this `mb_convert_encoding($str, "SJIS", "UTF-8");` and many other but it not getting convert back.
any valuable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, determine what is really in the table by doing

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) ...
```

If it is utf8, then the hex should be 3-byte sets like `E38xyy` for Katakana and Hiragana characters.  If not, then you possibly already have SJIS there.  (or something else)

Assuming that the table column says

```
col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8  -- (or utf8mb4)
```

then you can get a `SELECT` to convert to SJIS by doing

```
mysqli_charset('sjis');
mysqli_query( ... )
```

If, instead, you need to convert the table from utf8 to sjis, do something like

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET sjis;
```

That will convert all the columns in `tbl`, plus all the data in those columns to the specified charset.

Do not use `mb_*` or other conversion functions; it just adds to the confusion.

`ƒEƒCƒ“ƒhEƒŠƒ“ƒO`, if interpreted as latin1, is hex `834583438393836845838A8393834F`, which, if interpreted as sjis (or cp932) is `ウインドEリング` -- Is that what you expected?

That is, `ƒEƒCƒ“ƒhEƒŠƒ“ƒO` is Mojibake for sjis `ウインドEリング`.  Mojibake is usually fixed by doing the `mysqli_charset`, as above.

Comment: `ウインドEリング` is the desired result, thanks for the answer. but here a issue with some rows they have mix of content like `Luster Bangle  ƒVƒ‹ƒo[@ƒoƒ“ƒOƒ‹` how this possible to convert it ?

Comment: If some rows of a table are sjis and some are utf8, it is tricky to 'fix'.  Do you have a `WHERE` clause that will identify the 'wrongly' encoded rows?  I'll try to come up with an `UPDATE` to perform the conversion.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding this is `Luster Bangle  ƒVƒ‹ƒo[@ƒoƒ“ƒOƒ‹` a column's row value for column `name`. so column `name` have some value are `ƒEƒCƒ“ƒhEƒŠƒ“ƒO` but some are mix with English words like `Luster Bangle  ƒVƒ‹ƒo[@ƒoƒ“ƒOƒ‹`. so there will be solution for it?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`